# Wpf Interaction Behavior in nested DataGrids MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, behavior

I have a simple `DataGrid` with `RowDetailsTemplate` where the `DataTemplate` is also a `DataGrid`.

A `behavior` is used to bind in two way mode `DataGrid's SelectedItems` to the `ViewModel`.
The `behavior` is used both in main `DataGrid` and in subs `DataGrids` which are details of the main `DataGrid` rows.

I'm facing the problem that the behaviors in sub DataGrids seems to be never be referenced and each `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event in the sub DataGrid refers always to the behavior in the main DataGrid.

**THE VIEW**

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

    <DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              Height="Auto" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ObCol_Model}"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="false" BorderThickness="1"
              AlternatingRowBackground="#FFFFFFCC"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFA0A0A0"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFA0A0A0"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
              ColumnHeaderHeight="25" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowHeight="22" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              BorderBrush="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid Name="SubDataGrid"
                              Margin="10,0,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ObCol_SubModel}"
                              Height="Auto" Width="auto"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="false" BorderThickness="1"
                              AlternatingRowBackground="#FFFFFFCC"
                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFA0A0A0"
                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFA0A0A0"
                              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                              HeadersVisibility="Column"
                              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                              ColumnHeaderHeight="25" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowHeight="22" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                              BorderBrush="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SubSelectedItems}" />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        
                    <DataGrid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObCol_SubModel}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Style>

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Detail" Binding="{Binding Detail}" Width="80"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Detail Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="150"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Comment}" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

**THE BEHAVIOR**

```
public class DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (SelectedItems != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public IList SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedItemsChanged));

    private static void SelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = o as DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior;
        if (behavior == null) return;

        var oldValue = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var newValue = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (oldValue != null)
        {
            oldValue.CollectionChanged -= behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= behavior.DataGridSelectionChanged;
        }
        if (newValue != null)
        {
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)newValue)
            {
                behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }

            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += behavior.DataGridSelectionChanged;
            newValue.CollectionChanged += behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private bool _isUpdatingTarget;
    private bool _isUpdatingSource;

    void SourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingSource)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = true;

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = false;
        }
    }

    private void DataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingTarget)
            return;

        var selectedItems = this.SelectedItems;
        if (selectedItems == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = true;

            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Remove(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = false;
        }
    }

}
```

**THE VM**

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Model> myObCol_Model;
    private ObservableCollection<Model> mySelectedItems;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        mySelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

        myObCol_Model = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
        {
            new Model("100", "Hundred"),
            new Model("200", "Two Hundred"),
            new Model("300", "Three Hundred")
        };

        var item = new Model("400", "Four Hundred");
        item.AddSubModel(new SubModel("10", "Ten", "sub 10"));
        item.AddSubModel(new SubModel("20", "Twenty", "sub 20"));
        item.AddSubModel(new SubModel("30", "Thirty", "sub 30"));

        myObCol_Model.Add(item);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> ObCol_Model { get { return myObCol_Model; } }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return mySelectedItems; }
        set
        {
            if (mySelectedItems == value) return;

            mySelectedItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItems));
        }
    }
}
```

**THE MODELS**

```
public class Model : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<SubModel> myObCol_SubModel;
    private ObservableCollection<SubModel> mySubModelSelectedItems;

    public Model(string code, string name)
    {
        mySubModelSelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<SubModel>();

        Code = code;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubModel> ObCol_SubModel { get { return myObCol_SubModel; } }

    public void AddSubModel(SubModel subModel)
    { 
        if (myObCol_SubModel == null) myObCol_SubModel = new ObservableCollection<SubModel>();
        myObCol_SubModel.Add(subModel);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SubModel> SubSelectedItems
    {
        get { return mySubModelSelectedItems; }
        set
        {
            if (mySubModelSelectedItems == value) return;

            mySubModelSelectedItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SubSelectedItems));
        }
    }
}

public class SubModel
{
    public SubModel(string detail, string name, string comment)
    {
        Detail = detail;
        Name = name;
        Comment = comment;
    }

    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In MVVM the view model serves as an extra layer to decouple the view from the model. In other words, the view model exists so that you no longer have to bind directly to the model. Binding directly to the model violates the MVVM pattern and makes it obsolete. What is your behavior supposed to do? Why don't you handle DataGrid.SelectedItems in code-behind? Or even better add a IsSelected property to the data model.

Comment: The problem with SelectedItems is that it is difficult to set from e.g. the view model in scenarios where virtualization is enabled. It's also problematic as each manipulation of SelectedItems would trigger the MultiSelector to refresh itself, resulting in bad performance. So it's best if you don't hack around the limitation that was designed on purpose. Instead simply handle a dedicated IsSelected property on your data model as you would do with TreeView models.

Comment: Hi BionicCode, IsSelected property does not work when having large dataset. You will need to disable row virtualization, and that is exactly the case where you need it. I experimented such trouble with that solution

Comment: Your code doesn't work as it is. I was needed to add null reference check for the `behavior.AssociatedObject` in `SelectedItemsChanged`. I used also another namespace for behaviors: `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`. How have you checked, that behaviors in sub DataGrids never called?

Comment: Not sure what exact problems you were experiencing. Just make sure container recycling is disabled. And if I remember correctly you would also have to explicitly set the BindingMode to PropertyChanged for the row container bindings. You can still enable row virtualization, of course. From a UI design point of view it doesn't make sense to multi select items from the view model. This is a pure user operation. To highlight particular rows you can use a Style with triggers defined.

Comment: @Rekshino, In theory, the AssociatedObject can't be null, if so you can see that the sender and the e.Originalsouce are differents, this is the consequence of the problem reported here. And yes I checked behaviors in sub Datagrids, they are never called.

Comment: `AssociatedObject` can be `Null` if DP callback being called before the `OnAttached` occur, what was by me the case.

Comment: I just wonder why an answered question with a working solution could be downvoted? Downvote without any comment is just plain cowardice, are happy to live like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a behavior how it does work by me:

```
public class DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (SelectedItems != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }

        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += DataGridSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= DataGridSelectionChanged;
    }

    public IList SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedItemsChanged));

    private static void SelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = o as DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior;
        if (behavior == null || behavior.AssociatedObject==null)
            return;

        var oldValue = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var newValue = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (oldValue != null)
        {
            oldValue.CollectionChanged -= behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= behavior.DataGridSelectionChanged;
        }
        if (newValue != null)
        {
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)newValue)
            {
                behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }

            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += behavior.DataGridSelectionChanged;
            newValue.CollectionChanged += behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private bool _isUpdatingTarget;
    private bool _isUpdatingSource;

    void SourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingSource)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = true;

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = false;
        }
    }

    private void DataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingTarget)
            return;

        var selectedItems = this.SelectedItems;
        if (selectedItems == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = true;

            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Remove(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = false;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What was fixed?

- Added `AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += DataGridSelectionChanged;` to the `OnAttached()`, you should access `AssociatedObject` first after `OnAttached()` was called, otherwise `AssociatedObject` is `null`
- Added `override OnDetaching()`.
- Added `behavior.AssociatedObject==null` check to the DP changed call back.
- Added `e.Handled = true;` to the `DataGridSelectionChanged` event handler, in order to stop bubbling the event up, otherwise it comes by parent data grid.

I didn't check the rest of the code, just fixed errors which prevented selection to work.